# Select from database with Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, mybatis, spring-jdbc

I have never used Spring before, so just for testing I was using this in my JSP:

```
<sql:setDataSource
    var="myDS"
    driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@topsecret.mycompany.com...."
    user="user" password="password"
/>

...
...


 <sql:query var="data"   dataSource="${myDS}">
    SELECT TOP_SECRET, ALIEN_TYPE, CONTACT_WITH FROM EXTRATERRESTRIAL
 </sql:query>
```

and then I display it using a loop that puts it into an HTML table:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${data.rows}">
```

I have an update statement that is currently working and using the Java DAO:

```
@MyBatisRepository
public interface AlienDao {
    void updateAlien(@Param("topSecret") Integer topSecret, @Param("contactWith") String contactWith, @Param("alienType") String alienType);
}
```

and a corresponding XML:

```
<update id="updateAlien">
  update extraterrestrial
  set top_secret=#{topSecret}
  where alien_type=#{alienType} and contact_with=#{contactWith}
</update>
```

But I can't get a select statement to work using the DAO/XML.

What do I need to do for a select statement using this DAO/XML I have no reason to save that data into Java objects or map it to anything, as I only need it to be displayed.  I have tried several things that don't work.  What should I do to have the select be called from from a DAO and not directly in my JSP.

Comment: `@MyBatisRepository`, what library is that?

Comment: Its an internal thing... but I think it is the same as http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis just saved internally so they changed the name